# How to get QueryParam in factory provider (Angular4)

Tags: angular, angular-router, angular-di

I want to provide a constant in my application basing on QueryParam from url.

```
localhost:4200?flag=true
```

In my module providers I added

```
{ provide: FLAG, useFactory: FlagFactory, deps: [...] }
```

So I am interested if there is a way how to do it without parsing url manually

```
function FlagFactory() {
  return location.search.includes('flag');
}
```

Comment: What's the current behavior?

Comment: It works as I expect as I use `window.location.search`
but I would like to know if there is an 'angular' way to do it

Comment: There is no angular way.

Comment: maybe at least some nice workaround? or promise from angular developer to implement it? :)  or you think that it's not a correct way to set the provider?

Comment: Why would you need a workaround for `window.location.search`?

Comment: to use globals as less as possible

Answer (score 1):

What about using Angular Router?

The router tracks query parameters, so they should be available on you initial route '/'

your root component could have a route that allows this

```
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.sub = this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
       this.flag = params['flag']; 

    });
  }
```

Comment: Because your code will work only inside a component.
But before opening any component I need to check if the user may open it.

Comment: So I am sending request to API from guards.
And these requests require additional Header to be sent. Thats why I extended Http and BaseRequestOptions and added required Headers to each request.
  I am injecting the flag there.

Comment: do it in your root component (typically app.component) which you'll want to load before making any decisions about users etc

Comment: route params are empty in root component
so it is not the case

Answer (score 1):

I was able to do this by using Angular's [resolve](https://angular.io/guide/router#resolve-pre-fetching-component-data). Resolve allows you to access the route and query params BEFORE your route component is loaded.

In your case, I would create a resolver class that looks something like this:

```
@Injectable()
export class FlagRouteResolver implements Resolve<any> {
    constructor(private flagService: FlagService) {}

    resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot) {
        this.flagService.isFlagged = route.queryParamMap.get('flag');

        // Need to return an observable for all resolve() methods
        return Observable.of(null);
    }
}
```

And your AppModule should look something like this:

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        RouterModule.forRoot([{
            path: 'flagRoute',
            component: FlagComponent,
            resolve: { test: FlagRouteResolver }
        }]),
    ],
    providers: [
        FlagService,
        FlagRouteResolver
    ],
    declarations: [
        FlagComponent
    ]
})
```

So now, within your route component, you should be able to access that value immediately in the constructor like so:

```
constructor(private flagService: FlagService) {
    this.isFlagged = this.flagService.isFlagged;
}
```

But if you'd still like to inject it, you can also do it like so:

```
providers: [{
    provide: FLAG,
    useFactory: (flagService: FlagService) => {
        return this.flagService.isFlagged;
    },
    deps: [FlagService]
}]
```